# How do I reload the bracket without recreating it?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tournament

I am using http://www.aropupu.fi/bracket/ to create brackets for a tournament website, I store the json in my database, and whenever it is modified I update the json in the database. I have another page polling the json from the database. This works fine, the only problem is that currently when I retrieve the json from the database I have to recreate the whole bracket, thus it is destroyed and created, so the user is sent back to the beginning (if he was scrolling through it). Is there a better way to update the bracket with json without destroying and recreating it?

I've tried setting the values directly (shown below) by finding the tag inside the bracket and replacing the text. The problem with this is that the bracket is not notified of the change and doesn't advance the player.

```
// jQuery
function createBracket(id, json, started) {
  /*

  IF STARTED: don't replace whole bracket,
  replace values (solves issue with backscrolling)
  */

  section = $('.bracket-row[tourn-id="' + id + '"]');
  brack = section.find('.scrollable').eq(0);

  if (started && brack.find('.bracket').length != 0) {
    // started and bracket already built, dont replace whole json
    index = 1;
    $.each(json.results, function(i, results) {
      $.each(results, function(i2, result_column) {
        $.each(result_column, function(i3, team) {
          $.each(team, function(i4, player) {
            if (player != null) {
              tag = '[data-resultid="result-' + (index++) + '"]';
              $(tag).text(player);
            }
          });
        })
      })
    })
  } else {
    // whole bracket gets recreated here
    brack.bracket({
      init: json,
      decorator: {
        edit: acEditFn,
        render: acRenderFn
      }
    });
  }
}

function getBrackets() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      ids: ids
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

      $.each(data.brackets, function(id, json) {
        createBracket(id, $.parseJSON(json), data.started[id]);
      })

      setTimeout(getBrackets, 1001);
    }
  });
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try removing the " != 0 ".

Comment: that is not the problem, i can change the text, but changing the text doesn't notify the bracket, and doesn't advance the player.

Comment: Use " $( document ).find( element ) " to select elements that are dynamic. Or use the event "DOMNodeInserted" to listen to changes.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. I know how to find elements, etc. I just need to update the bracket with new json every 5 seconds. If I re initialize the bracket with json it works, but scrolls you back to the beginning. There is a way to get the data according to the documentation but there seems to be no way to set the data (json) besides recreating the bracket.

Comment: Add a condition where the json will only be updated if there's a new/change in data from the database.

Comment: Ryan, that is a good idea! I guess I don't have to recreate every single time, but when I do it still scrolls back. I'll do that for now until I find a fix.